# background z-index with functioning anchors

Tags: anchor, z-index

So I've got this code:

```
<div style="position:fixed;left:0;top:65px;border:1px solid blue;background-color:#D5BF9D;width:190px;z-index:-1">
        <h1>title</h1>
        <nav><ul>
            <li><a href="#apples">Apple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#s">s</a></li>
        </ul></nav>
    </div>
    <div class="italic" style="border:1px solid red;z-index:99;background-color:white">Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.</div>
```

It works except the links no longer function since the z-index is -1. Is there a way to maintain the look but give functionality to the links? I tried making the current link div transparent with a z-index of 0 and putting another div behind it with the desired color, but no go. Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:fixed;left:0;top:65px;border:1px solid blue;background-color:#D5BF9D;width:190px;z-index:-1"></div>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <div style="background-color:transparent"><nav><ul>
            <li><a href="#apples">Apple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#s">s</a></li>
        </div></ul></nav>
    <div class="italic" style="border:1px solid red;background-color:white">Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.</div>
```

I ended up doing the above. create an empty div with z-index:-1 outside of the main section with the desired background. Then making the main section background-color:transparent.